# Resolve dpkg-divert clash for /usr/lib/os-release

Tags: dpkg

My `dpkg` is broken, so I can't upgrade packages.  Running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` produces:

```
ben@Friday:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up pop-default-settings (4.0.6~1611854075~20.04~6a2277e) ...
Leaving 'diversion of /etc/gdm3/custom.conf to /etc/gdm3/custom.conf.diverted by pop-default-settings'
Leaving 'diversion of /etc/issue to /etc/issue.diverted by pop-default-settings'
Leaving 'diversion of /etc/issue.net to /etc/issue.net.diverted by pop-default-settings'
Leaving 'diversion of /etc/legal to /etc/legal.diverted by pop-default-settings'
Leaving 'diversion of /etc/update-motd.d/10-help-text to /etc/update-motd.d/10-help-text.diverted by pop-default-settings'
Leaving 'diversion of /etc/update-motd.d/50-motd-news to /etc/update-motd.d/50-motd-news.diverted by pop-default-settings'
Leaving 'diversion of /etc/lsb-release to /etc/lsb-release.diverted by pop-default-settings'
Leaving 'diversion of /etc/os-release to /etc/os-release.diverted by pop-default-settings'
dpkg-divert: error: 'diversion of /usr/lib/os-release to /usr/lib/os-release.diverted by pop-default-settings' clashes with 'diversion of /usr/lib/os-release to /usr/lib/os-release.oem-release by oem-release'
dpkg: error processing package pop-default-settings (--configure):
 installed pop-default-settings package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pop-desktop:
 pop-desktop depends on pop-default-settings; however:
  Package pop-default-settings is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pop-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pop-default-settings
 pop-desktop
```

I am concerned about `pop-default-settings` and `oem-release` both being core system packages trying to divert the same file.  (I don't work with dpkg much, so I am hesitant to just remove one of the diversions.)  I have searched around and not found good results for exactly this error.  Any suggestions for how to address this?  Should I remove a divert?  Which one?

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use the Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu & flavors are the many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: `pop-default-settings` is a 3rd party package in Ubuntu, is not from Ubuntu repositories thus is not core at all.  If you're using an on-topic system, the package should be removed as you've polluted your sources & you're not running a Ubuntu system, ie. check `ubuntu-support-status` or `ubuntu-security-status` (ie. whichever is appropriate for your *unstated* release)  .. Ubuntu Security Team do not evaluate 3rd party packages found in PPAs, all *core* packages are found in 'main' which is checked for security issues (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

Comment: That makes sense, my apologies.  Feel free to close this.